# Странный и странник

Tags: однокоренные-слова

В словах "странный" и "странник" один корень. Но как эти слова связаны друг с другом по смыслу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший вопрос.  Связь действительно есть,  причем очень близкая.
*Странник* напрямую происходит от странный, и далее от праславянского *strona*, которое, как легко понять, породило и *страна*. Более того, до относительно недавнего времени *странный* имело значение *странствующий*, что еще не до конца изжито языком, сравните: странноприимный дом: для *странников*, не для *странных*.

Касательно же самого изменения значения *странный* со *странствующий* на *необычный*, *непонятный*, то о причинах остаётся только строить предположения, поскольку значение у *сторона* тоже несколько изменилось со временем, сравните: *стоять в стороне* - находиться рядом, было у strona, и такое значение. Возможно, что именно оно развилось в *необычный*, *несоответствующий (нормам или ожиданиям)*, т.е. *сторонний, находящийся в стороне* от таких норм.
Но это, повторю, это - версии и догадки. Документально подтвердить такие вещи обычно бывает крайне сложно...

Answer (score 1):

Странник - путешествующий по странам (сторонам).

Странный - с другой страны (стороны), со своими обычаями и привычками